# On what interval does the function $f(x)=-\sin x$ increases and ....

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Can you explain me how do I find the intervals where the function:$$f(x)=-\sin x$$ is increasing and decreasing.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you understand how the derivative of a function works?

Comment: Check $f'(x)$. $f(x)$ strictly increasing when $f'(x)> 0$ and $f(x)$ strictly deacrasing when $f'(x)<0$

Comment: Have you tried looking at the graph of this function?

Answer (score 2):

Check the derivative of $f(x)=-sinx$

$f^{'}(x)=-cosx$

Are you getting somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

What is the derivative of $f$?  By definition, the intervals for which $f'$ is positive will be the same intervals for which $f$ is increasing.  Similarly, when $f'$ is negative, then $f$ is decreasing.

Hopefully this helps, but it really helps us help you when you provide us with as much background as possible.  For example, useful information includes whether you know calculus, what you've tried, and where you are getting stuck.

If you do not know calculus, I recommend first trying to sketch the graph of $\sin(x)$ with help from the unit circle.  Then, the negative will reflect the graph over the $y$-axis (why?).

Comment: I know how to use derivative all this stuff, but you see, here I've got that on the interval $(-\infty;{\pi\over 2}]$ the function is decreasing but if we take the second interval to $+\infty$  then I do not quiet understand.

Comment: And what I do not understand is that if I substitute for example $\pi$ in the derivative of the original function I get the value $1$ so the function is supposed to be increasing ,but what about $2\pi$. If we substitute $2\pi$ we get that the value of the derivative in this point is $-1$!?

Comment: Your second comment is correct.  $f$ is an oscillating function, so there will be an infinite number of intervals for which the function is increasing, and an infinite number for which the function is decreasing.  Check out the graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-sin%28x%29

Answer (score 1):

here is the image of -sin(x)
[image]

and here is the image of -cos(x) which is the derivative of -sin(x)
[image]

compare the interval of -cos(x) is positive and the interval -sin(x) increase,
compare the interval of -cos(x) is negative and the interval -sin(x) decrease.
I hope it helps.